# Wrong images on wrong items in ListView even if i use viewholder

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I know this question has been asked here many times before. But not any of these solutions worked for me. I am trying to fetch some data from server and display it in customlistview. I have done it successfully but problem is when i scroll down the list. It show wrong images on wrong row. Like image of row(1) on row(2) and image of row(2) on row(1) or repeating same image. I am using UIL libaray for loading images.
Below is code that i am using.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
Main values;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public CustomListAdapter(Context context,Main values){
    this.context=context;
    this.values=values;
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return values.getPosts().size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    ImageLoader imageLoader=ImageLoader.getInstance();
    if(convertView==null){
        viewHolder= new ViewHolder();
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);
        viewHolder.category=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        viewHolder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.date=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        viewHolder.imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.category.setText(values.getPosts().get(position).getCategories().get(0).getTitle());
    viewHolder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(values.getPosts().get(position).getTitle()));
    viewHolder.date.setText(values.getPosts().get(position).getDate());
    ImageSize targetSize = new ImageSize(700,228);
    final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
    imageLoader.loadImage(values.getPosts().get(position).getThumbnail_images().getFull().getUrl(),targetSize, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = loadedImage;
            Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            finalViewHolder.imageView.setBackground(dr);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
private static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView category;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView date;
    public ImageView imageView;
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of making `viewHolder` final, make the Bitmap final.

Comment: new to programming. Kindly guide me how to cancel pervious image request?

Comment: try to use `displayImage` instead `loadImage` I never use UIL but it should  cancel previous request for given ImageView instance ... and next time read the docs and look at the samples... (ImageListFragment from this library's sample is using `displayImage`)

Comment: @Selvin `"and next time read the docs and look at the samples"` please don't make me laugh, please

Comment: why? That's the way in which I'm starting using new library :) (I get the irony)

Comment: @Selvin yes: the keyword is **you**, and you are not "programmer by permutation"

Comment: ok i am using displayImage now. Actually i had to use loadImage to get bitmap of image. Well i still have that same issue now. When i scroll down it display wrong image on wrong item for 2 seconds then actuall image comes

Comment: so what method is called when "you scroll down"? did you do some logging?

Comment: getView gets call when scroll down

Comment: futhermore this displayImage croped the image now it is not taking whole width of imageview

Comment: and when / where / how "actuall image" is set in your new item?

Comment: after delay of 2 or 3 seconds. I think maybe it is problem of caching. And i am testing it on emulator

Comment: ok "when" answered, now "where / how"

Comment: I have an imageview. It get sets to actual image after 2 seconds when i scroll down or sometimes it takes more time. I am sorry, but your how,where are confusing me.

Comment: actuall images get set everytime when getview gets call. Answer to you how and where.

Comment: so if you dont want the "other" image to be shown during those 2-3 seconds setup a "placeholder" / "please wait" image for that short period of time

Comment: I can wait for that. But i don't want to show wrong images. I mean images of other posts there. that's my point.

Comment: Can i show progress bar there until images load? if yes then how?

Comment: so as i said show "placeholder" / "please wait" image / drawable

Comment: problem is solved. I have post it in answer below. Thanks anyway people

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem cuz i wasn't caching the images. so whenever i scroll down it sent a request to download image(it takes time) then it inflate the actual image on right item.

I added following code in application class.

```
  DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().
    cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true)
    .build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
    .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```